# Draw shadow with canvas around <img> during onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

**HTML :**

```
<div id="presentationViewContainer">
    <img id="presentationView" />
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#presentationViewContainer {
  display : none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 573px;
  height: 516px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#presentationView {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

I would like to draw a shadow around the image when the image is loaded into my  tag.
How can i do this using canvas ?

I tried the following code, but with it, i need to create a new div element :

```
$( "#presentationView" ).load(function(evt) {
      // Handler for .load() called.
      var image = evt.target;
            var w = image.width;
            var h = image.height;

            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var g = canvas.getContext('2d');
            g.shadowColor = "#000000";
            g.shadowBlur = 10;
            g.shadowOffsetX = 0;
            g.shadowOffsetY = 0;
            g.drawImage(image, 20, 20);
            g.fillText("Text shadow in canvas", 10, 20)
    });
```

Comment: Do you have a canvas element with the id `canvas` in your DOM?

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to dynamically modify the `<img id="presentationView" />` tag instead ?

Comment: Sure. Modify it to what?